# What's the difference between NSIndexSet and NSSet?

Tags: cocoa, nsset, nsindexset

I'm a bit new to Cocoa and I was reading about `NSIndexSet`. Why is it necessary? It seems to me that `NSIndexSet` is nothing but a `NSSet` of integers, is that right? What's the purpose of creating a separate collection alltogether?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple reasons:

1. `NSIndexSet` stores unsigned integer primitive types, whereas `NSSet` stores objects.
2. `NSIndexSet` is optimized for storing unsigned integers, specifically a set of integers into another data structure like an `NSArray`.

Comment: To elaborate on #2, NSIndexSet lets you iterate through the indexes in order or in reverse order. An NSSet is unordered, and an NSOrderedSet is manually ordered (meaning you can break the order by inserting an object at the wrong position).

Comment: Got it. Another thing I just noticed. NSIndexSet actually uses NSRange to store consecutive indexes, indeed very optimized for storing index value into other collections.

Comment: Operations over `NSSet` are O(1) (hashing), while most of the `NSIndexSet` operations are O(N) (looping).